# How to resolve angular error: "Cannot find module 'ansi-colors'"?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, nvm

Every time I tried to enter a command that start with "ng" I got this error, the complete error is:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077
const err = new Error(message);
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'ansi-colors'Require stack:
```

- ```
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/utilities/color.js
  ```
- ```
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.jsat Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/utilities/color.js:34:33)at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',requireStack: ['/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/src/utilities/color.js','/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js']}
  ```

```
Node.js v18.18.0
```

I tried to unistall and install ansi-color but it doesn't work

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: The command for installing ansi-colors is not the one you mentioned (`npm install -g @angular/cli`), but this one `npm install --save ansi-colors`.